# gdb debug in docker failed

Tags: docker, debugging, gdb

> envs:
> host:centos
> docker:ubuntu 16 nivida-docker
> program:c++ websocket

desc:
when I use gdb in docker ,I can't use breakpoint ,it just says:**warning: error disabling address space randomization: operation not permitted**.I see alot of resolutions to this question,all of them tell me to add :**--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined**to my docker file ,so I did it.here is my docker file:

```
!/bin/sh
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}") && pwd)
PROJECT_ROOT="$( cd "${SCRIPT_DIR}/.." && pwd )"
echo "PROJECT_ROOT = ${PROJECT_ROOT}"

run_type=$1
docker_name=$2
sudo docker run \
  --name=${docker_name} \
  --privileged \
  --network host \
  -it --rm \
  --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined \
  -v ${PROJECT_ROOT}/..:/home \
  -v /ssd3:/ssd3 \
  xxxx/xx/xxxx:xxxx \
  bash
```

but when restart the container and run gdb ,it always killed like below:

```
(gdb) r -c conf/a.json -p 8075
Starting program: /home/Service/bin/Service --args -c conf/a.json -p 8075
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Killed
```

I don't known where is wrong ,anyone have any opinions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined`

Comment: I tried it ,just like my docker file ,but the same ,be killed,I don't know why @)@